# Java Threads: Automatic Termination

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, client

I want to know if this thread (refer to code snippet) that is being created will be terminated automatically in garbage collection once it finishes it's job.

I was creating a rudimentary chat program to learn how to work with sockets, make clients, and make servers.  I quickly discovered that if I wanted to be able to send and receive messages from the client, and not update only on sending, I would need to multi-thread the client.  One thread for receiving messages and updating my GUI, and one for sending.  I have the following code snippet, which is called whenever a button on my chatroom GUI fires an `ActionEvent`.  I became concerned once I noticed that every time I sent a message, a thread was being created with a sequentially higher number.  I was worried that the previous threads were not being properly deleted and were still in memory, thus the higher number.

**Code:**

```
public void send(String message)
{
    //Create a new thread so that the client can receive messages while it's sending them.
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        /* (non-Javadoc)
         * @see java.lang.Runnable#run()
         */
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                System.out.println("Writing chars");
                output.writeUTF(message);
            } catch (IOException exception)
            {
                System.out.println("Error attempting to write: " + message + " to the server.");
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }   
        }
    });
    thread.start();
}
```

Comment: Why are you creating a new thread each time the client wants to send a message?  You need several threads for such a client but they should run for the duration of the program and add and remove messages from internal queues.

Comment: You might want to use some Queue, eg. [BlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html).
I suggest you reading something about Java Concurrency in general, like this [Java Concurrency Tutorial by Jenkov](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/index.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After your `run()` method returns, that `Thread` will terminate and eventually be garbage collected. You see incrementing id numbers because you are starting new threads for each such action - which is not an advised architecture, but does work.

Comment: Why is it not advised, if you don't mind me asking?  Also, thanks for the fast answer :)

Comment: There is a lot of overhead to spinning up a thread. What you generally do is start a thread to 'listen' to a queue. When something is on that queue, it processes it and goes back to listening. This way the thread startup overhead is avoided. In addition, it is trivial to know what thread is doing the work!